# How to Build a Scroll Indicator within my Carousel

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i'm creating a carousel component using react.

I want to add a scroll indicator into it. May be placed inside/outside of the element.

[image]

The question is, which the appropriate element to make the indicator?

- use `ul` > `li` > `a`
- use series of `<button>`
- use `form` > `radio`
- use `<progress>`
- or any suggestion?

I will implement a different styling for indicating selected item & handle click event to scroll the slide.

Comment: It's worth looking how some other carousels are created, for instance React Responsive Carousel uses li elements for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel but owl-carousel uses <button>s https://owlcarousel2.github.io/

Comment: i'm creating a framework/lib. One of them is the carousel.
i can't include 3rd party comp, i need every components working together with shared config, themes, etc.
it's a reverse engineered from many other carousel.
it just missing the indicator. i want a separated indi's comp outside the carousel.

Comment: I wasn't recommending you to use those, just look at the way they are implemented to see what the best implementation would be for you.

Comment: i know the work of them. I doubt the kind of element for making the indicator. Which is the most appropriate one for semantic html?